# PHP If variable = a and not = b

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

php 7.3.18

mysql 5.7.30

Here is the relevant code, which fails immediately so I would appreciate it being corrected.

The first 'if' is ok, but the issue is with the 2nd + 3rd.

$targetcatid2, $targetcatid3, $targetweight2, $targetweight3 have been properly declared.

The object is that if a product is in Category2 and not in Category3 then the weight will become Weight2
and vice-a-versa.

```
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($select2);

if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid){
    $row['product_weight']= $targetweight;
}

if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid2 && !== $targetcatid3){
    $row['product_weight']= $targetweight2;
}

if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid3 && !== $targetcatid2){
    $row['product_weight']= $targetweight3;
}
```

My latest effort is:

if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid){
$row['product_weight']= $targetweight; }

if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid2 && $row2['category_id']!== $targetcatid3){
$row['product_weight']= $targetweight2; }

elseif($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid3 && $row2['category_id']!== $targetcatid2){
$row['product_weight']= $targetweight3; }

elseif($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid2 && $row2['category_id']== $targetcatid3){
$row['product_weight']= $targetweight3; }

I have found that the new condition does not work, even on its own.
But do not understand why:

elseif($row2['category_id'] == $targetcatid2 && $row2['category_id'] == $targetcatid3){ $row['product_weight'] = $targetweight3; }

Comment: You have to define what you are comparing against in all cases... `$row2['category_id']== $targetcatid2 && $row2['category_id'] !== $targetcatid3`

Comment: Anyone able to suggest why the 4th if does not work?

Comment: It looks like you are checking is a value is equal to 2 different things, which unless both `$targetcatid2` and `$targetcatid3` are the same value then it cannot equal them both.

Comment: They are both categories which a product can be in. So, in my products_categories table, there are 60+ products which exist in both cattid2 AND catid3. .

Comment: But the last test says it must be in BOTH categories.

Comment: That is correct. Any product can be assigned to any number of categories. In this case, I am only interested in the categories represented by targetcatid2 & targetcatid3.

Comment: There are 60+ products which are in Both the categories

Comment: So what does `$row2['category_id']` contain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215890/discussion-between-aspied-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: Transferred to Chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215890/discussion-between-aspied-and-nigel-ren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not understanding the && operator correctly.

Instead of this

```
if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid2 && !== $targetcatid3){
```

You should separately compare the conditions.

```
if($row2['category_id']== $targetcatid2 && $row2['category_id'] !== $targetcatid3){
```

Comment: Thanks You for your speedy response. I had actually just realised that myself.

Comment: in this case, you need elseif, not multiple if.